# A combinatorial question on Steiner systems from book of Dixon-Mortimer

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, combinatorial-geometry, permutation-matrices

Let $S(t,k,v)$ be a Steiner system.

[Means: we have a set $S=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\}$ with $v$ elements, some **blocks**($\equiv$subsets of $S$) $B_1,B_2,\ldots$ of size $k$, such that, **every** subset of $S$ of size $t$ is in unique $B_i$.]

**Assume:** Each element of $S$ lies in exactly $r$ blocks $B_i$.

Let $A$ be the incidence matrix of this system: $(i,j)$-th enetry is
$$\langle \alpha_i, B_j\rangle=\begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{ if } \alpha_i\in B_j \\ 0 & \mbox{ otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
**Problem:** Show that $AA^t$ is ($v\times v$) matrix with diagonal entries $r$ and non-diagonal entries $1$.

*What I did:*

$$(AA^t)_{ij}= \sum_k A_{ik} (A^t)_{kj} = \sum_k \langle \alpha_i, B_k\rangle \cdot \langle \alpha_j, B_k\rangle.$$
So, if $i=j$, then, by **assumption**, there are exactly $r$ many blocks which contains $\alpha_i=\alpha_j$, so diagonal entry of $AA^t$ is $r$.

*What about non-diagonal entries?* For example, why $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ can not be in more than one blocks (unless we have a Steiner system $S(2,k,v)$?)

---

**Ref:** Permutation Groups: Dixon and Mortimer, Theorem $6.2$A (p. $180$-$181$)

Comment: This is only true if $t=2$. If $t>2$ then every $v$ points are contained in a unique block, and every two points are contained in $\frac{(v-2)(v-3) \cdots(v-t+1)}{(k-2)(k-3)\cdots(k-t+1)}$ blocks.

Comment: But Dixon-Mortimer state that it is $1$; I confused, so posted question here. So exact entry should be that you mentioned, right?